# Algorithm to identifying all the common subsequences in two strings

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, string-matching

I need to identify all the sub-sequences of given two strings. Longest common sub-sequence will only identify the longest one. But here I want all sub sequences exceeding a threshold value. Any specific algorithm or approach ?

Something like this

```
Julie loves me more than Linda loves me
Jane likes me more than Julie loves me
```

if the threshold value is 2, the following are the common sub-sequences of these 2 strings

```
me more than
loves me
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> allCS;//create an empty set
String[] subStrings = getSubSequences(string2); //find the subsequence of string2(smaller string)
for (String str : subStrings) {
   String lcs = LCS(string1, str);
   if(lcs.length > THRESHOLD) {
       allCS.put(lcs);
   }
}
```

Here, `getSubSequences(String s)` returns all the subsequence of the given string parameter and `LCS(String s1, String s2)` returns the LCS of `s1` and `s2`.

`getSubSequences(String s)` can be implemented using bitmask approach or recursively.

`LCS(String s1, String s2)` can be implemented using `O(n^2)` dynamic programming approach and later track the path backward in DP table to print the longest sub-sequenceb string.

This won't be efficient if the smaller string is pretty long because there are `2^length(string) - 1` sub-sequences possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an algorithm question so I think language does not matter. My approach is generate all subsequences between these two strings, and find the ones exceeding the threshold.

Python code (Java should not be a lot harder):

```
def common_subsequences(a, b, threshold):
    # tokenize two string (keep order)
    tokens_a = a.split()
    tokens_b = b.split()
    # store all common subsequences
    common = set()
    # with each token in a
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens_a):
        # if it also appears in b
        # then this should be a starting point for a common subsequence
        if token in tokens_b:
            # get the first occurence of token in b
            # and start from there
            j = tokens_b.index(token)
            k = i
            temp = token
            # since we need all subsequences, we get length-1 subsequences too 
            common.add(temp)
            # while still have token in common
            while j < len(tokens_b) and k < len(tokens_a):
                if j + 1 < len(tokens_b) and k + 1 < len(tokens_a) and tokens_b[j+1] == tokens_a[k+1]:
                    temp += " " + tokens_b[j+1]
                    j += 1
                    k += 1
                    # adding (new) common subsequences
                    common.add(temp)
                # or else we break
                else:
                    break
    # we only get the ones having length >= threshold
    return [s for s in common if len(s.split()) >= threshold]

a = "Julie loves me more than Linda loves me"
b = "Jane likes me more than Julie loves me"
print common_subsequences(a, b, 2)
```

all common_subsequences:

```
set(['me', 'more than', 'Julie', 'Julie loves', 'Julie loves me', 'me more', 'loves', 'more', 'than', 'me more than', 'loves me'])
```

common_subsequences that >= threshold:

```
['more than', 'Julie loves', 'Julie loves me', 'me more', 'me more than', 'loves me']
```